# Cakephp: Group by foreign key id and order by published date

Tags: sql, cakephp

```
public function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'order'=>array('published_date'=>'desc'),
        'group'=>'book_id',
        'conditions'=>array('Chapter.published'=>1,'Chapter.published_date <= NOW()')
    );
    $chapters = $this->paginate();
    $this->set('chapters',$chapters);

}
```

My database have table *Book*, *Chapter*. Each book has many chapter

Table *Chapter* has field '*book_id*', that is foreign key reference table *Book* primary key (id).

Here is my index page. The idea is to get latest chapter from each book and order by published date.In controller *ChapterController*, I use *group by* statement but it didn't get the latest chapter, it get the first chapter form each book.

So,please help me fix it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe that group by will use the first row that is naturally in your results, and I do not think there is a simple way to sort your results before the group by is applied.  But I think the following query will get you the results you want:

```
SELECT * FROM books INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE chapters.published = 1 AND chapters.published_date <= NOW() ORDER BY chapters.published_date DESC) AS Chapter ON Chapter.book_id = books.id GROUP BY books.id
```

I think the following is how the CakePHP should look  (I'm assuming you're paginating Book):

```
$this->Book->recursive = -1;  //Join manually instead
$this->paginate = array(
     'order' => array('published_date' => 'desc'),
     'group'  => 'Book.id',
     'joins' => array(
           array(
               'table' => '(SELECT * FROM chapters)',
               'alias' => 'Chapter',
               'conditions' => array(
                      'Chapter.book_id = Book.id',
                      'Chapter.published' => 1,
                      'Chapter.published_date <= NOW()',
               ),
               'type' => 'inner',
               'order' => array('published_date' => 'desc'),
           ),
      ),
 );
```

Comment: Thanks Kai, I try use your suggest but it uneffective. It only get Book info, without Chapter info. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at the actual SQL query it's generating.  It's definitely possible that I made a mistake when writing the CakePHP query.